# combine and merge rows in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a SAS Table like:

```
DATA test; 
   INPUT id sex $ age inc r1 r2 Zaehler work $; 
   DATALINES; 
 1  F  35 17  7 2 1 w
17  M  40 14  5 5 1 w
33  F  35  6  7 2 1 w
49  M  24 14  7 5 1 w
65  F  52  9  4 7 1 w
81  M  44 11  7 7 1 w
2   F  35 17  6 5 1 n
18  M  40 14  7 5 1 n
34  F  47  6  6 5 1 n
50  M  35 17  5 7 1 w
; 
PROC PRINT; RUN;

proc sort data=have;
by county;
run;
```

I want compare rows if sex and age is equal and build sum over Zaehler. For example:

1  F  35 17  7 2 1 w

and

33  F  35  6  7 2 1 w

sex=f and age=35 are equale so i want to merge them like: 
id sex age inc r1 r2 Zaehler work 
 1  F  35  17  7  2     2     w

I thought i can do it with proc sql but i can't use sum in proc sql. Can someone help me out?

Comment: How do you want to deal with other columns?

Comment: They don't matter. It can be taken the value of the first row. The second row should be deletet.

Answer (score 4):

PROC SUMMARY is the normal way to compute statistics.

```
proc summary data=test nway ;
  class sex age ;
  var Zaehler;
  output out=want sum= ;
run;
```

Why would you want to include variables other than SEX, AGE and Zaehler in the output?

Comment: Just a small typo, last line should have _out=want_ instead of _data=want_

Answer (score 3):

Your requirement is not difficult to understand or to satisfy, however, I am not sure what is your underline reason for doing this. Explain more on your purpose may help to facilitate better answers that work from the root of your project. Although I have a feeling the PROC MEAN may give you better matrix, here is a one step PROC SQL solution to get you the summary as well as retaining "the value of first row":

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select id, sex , age, inc, r1, r2, sum(Zaehler) as Zaehler, work
from test
group by sex, age
having id = min(id) /*This is tell SAS only to keep the row with the smallest id within the same sex,age group*/
;
quit;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use proc sql to sum over sex and age

```
proc sql;
create table sum as 
select 
    sex
    ,age
    ,sum(Zaehler) as Zaehler_sum
from test 
    group by 
    sex
    ,age;
quit;
```

You can than join it back to the main table if you want to include all the variables

```
proc sql;
create table test_With_Sum as 
select 
    t.*
    ,s.Zaehler_sum
from test t
    inner join sum s on t.sex = s.sex
    and t.age = s.age
    order by
    t.sex
    ,t.age
;
quit;
```

You can write it all as one proc sql query if you wish and the order by is not needed, only added for a better visibility of summarised results

Answer (score 1):

Not a good solution. But it should give you some ideas.

```
DATA test; 
   INPUT id sex $ age inc r1 r2 Zaehler work $; 
   DATALINES; 
 1  F  35 17  7 2 1 w
17  M  40 14  5 5 1 w
33  F  35  6  7 2 1 w
49  M  24 14  7 5 1 w
65  F  52  9  4 7 1 w
81  M  44 11  7 7 1 w
2   F  35 17  6 5 1 n
18  M  40 14  7 5 1 n
34  F  47  6  6 5 1 n
50  M  35 17  5 7 1 w
; 
run; 

data t2;
    set test;
    nobs = _n_;
run;

proc sort data=t2;by descending sex descending age descending nobs;run;

data t3;
    set t2;
    by descending sex descending age;
    if first.age then count = 0;
    count + 1;
    zaehler = count;
    if last.age then output;
run;

proc sort data=t3 out=want(drop=nobs count);by nobs sex age;run;
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. Here is my final code.

```
    proc sql;
create table sum as 
select distinct
    sex
    ,age
    ,sum(Zaehler) as Zaehler
from test 
WHERE work = 'w'
    group by 
    sex
    ,age
    ;
PROC PRINT;quit;
```

I just modify the code a little bit. I filtered the w and i merg the Columns with the same value. 
It was just an example the real Data is much bigger and has more Columns and rows.